# Only Execute "if" for 5 seconds, then move on to "else"

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in executing "if" on mouse click (which changes the behavior of particles), then after 5 seconds moving on to "else" (which changes the behavior back to normal). I've tried to use a setTimeout that increases 'this.index' by one with a time delay, but I'm having no luck.

Right now it successfully executes "if" on click and then "else" on a second click.

Quite new to this so if my question or intent is way off, please let me know.

```
 this.index = 0;
 this.renderer = renderer;
 this.gravity = gravity;
 this.randomBehaviour = randomBehaviour;

 handleMouseDown(e) {
        this.index++;
    
    if (this.index % 2 === 1){
      this.randomBehaviour.reset(50, 50, 0.1);
      this.gravity.reset(0);
  } else {
      this.randomBehaviour.reset(2, 2, 0.2);
      this.gravity.reset(0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a `setTimeout` and simulate a click:

```
 this.index = 0;
 this.renderer = renderer;
 this.gravity = gravity;
 this.randomBehaviour = randomBehaviour;

 handleMouseDown(e) {
  this.index++;
  if (this.index % 2 === 1){
    this.randomBehaviour.reset(50, 50, 0.1);
    this.gravity.reset(0);
    setTimeout(() => e.target.click(), 5000); // 5000 = delay in ms
  } else {
    this.randomBehaviour.reset(2, 2, 0.2);
    this.gravity.reset(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the e.target.click portion. Getting "Cannot read property 'click' of null". Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: @Abevigodasson How are you calling `handleMouseDown()`? Are you passing the click event to it? Try adding `console.log(e)` before the timeout.

Comment: Don't know if this is allowed but here's a link to the code in sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/proton-imagezone-forked-wf0zh?file=/src/components/Particles.jsx